# Why is this function not a solution to this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

If we consider the autonomous ODE:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x) = ax$, where $a$ is in $\mathbb{R}$, $x(0) = x_{0}$

then this has a unique solution for every initial condition $x(0) = x_{0}$ since $f$ is continuous and so is $\frac{df}{dx}$, namely:

$x(t) = x_{0}e^{at}$.

But if we just consider the initial condition $x(0) = 0$, fix a constant $b > 0$, and define a function:

$z(t) = e^{a(t - b)}$    if $t > b$,

and   $z(t) = 0$     if $t \leq b$.

Now I differentiated and plugged it into the ODE (not realising there was a discontinuity at $t = b$) and found that it seemed to be a solution to the IVP ($x(0) = 0$) - if this was a solution to the IVP  for any choice of $b$, then it would violate uniqueness of solutions as we would have infinitely many choices of $b$ that we could make - so clearly it is not a solution to the IVP, since we already know $x(t) = 0$ for all $t$ is a solution to the IVP, and $z \neq x$.

**But why is $z(t)$ not a solution?**

Someone pointed out to me that it was because $z(t)$ was *discontinuous* at $t = b$ and was clearly *not differentiable* there - initially I found this satisfactory but then I looked at another example in my lecture notes:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2$, $x(0) = x_{0}$

The solution is $x(t) = \frac{x_{0}}{1 - x_{0}t}$, and it was said that the solution 'blows up' for $t = \frac{1}{x_{0}}$ as we are dividing by 0 there. But this solution is discontinuous and not differentiable at $t = \frac{1}{x_{0}}$ just like $z$, but is being recognised as a solution. Indeed, my lecture notes say the solution is only for 'finite time'. What does this mean?

So do we say $z$ is a solution only for 'finite time'? What would/does this mean, that we ignore the point $t = b$? But then we still have the problem of this being a different solution to $x(t) = 0$.

I am very confused by this and feel I must have misunderstood something somewhere. Hopefully I haven't been too vague or unclear - I'd be happy to clarify anything in the comments! Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: "But if we just consider the initial condition $x(0)=0$ ..." Why can you do that ?

Comment: All I meant by this was, if we take the function $z$ as defined in my post, doesn't this generate infinitely many solutions to that IVP via different choices of $b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed function $z(t)$ *is* a solution, but only on the interval $t < b$.

Uniqueness means that whenever you have a function $x(t)$ which satisfies the ODE on an open interval $I$ containing the point $t=0$ and satisfies the initial condition $x(0)=0$, then it has to satisfy $x(t)=0$ for every $t$ in that interval $I$.

And this is the case for your function $z(t)$ (for any choice of $b>0$), so it doesn't violate the uniqueness theorem.

(Regarding the finite time stuff, that solution blows up to infinity “automatically”, just by doing what the ODE says that it should do. So it's not just a matter of constructing a function which jumps “artificially”, as in your first example, it's an unavoidable issue which is built into that particular ODE.)

Comment: Good answer. I'd suggest explaining about the two branches of $\frac{x_0}{1+x_0t}$ and how the IVP is one or the other based on the initial value.

Comment: @IanMiller: Nice idea, but I didn't feel like digging too deep into those matters here. Add another answer, if you like.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think that's pretty much cleared it up, but what about the interval $t > b$, is $z$ a solution for then as well? Also, definitions of uniqueness I have seen imply that the solution is unique maybe for only a finite time around the initial time, so in this case maybe only in an interval $(-e, e)$? But if we choose $b < e$, then isn't saying $x(t) = 0$ for $t < b$ different to saying $x(t) = 0$ for all $t$.

Comment: That last question of mine is likely a very stupid one but it just seems like uniqueness guarantees that there exists an interval $(-e, e)$ such that any solution satisfying $x(0) = 0$ is the same on this time interval, that is, it is exactly $x(t) = 0$ for all $t$ in $(-e, e)$, but this is not the case if we choose $b < e$, or is having some restricted possible choice of t, i.e. b < t ok and not violating uniqueness?

Comment: Ah I think I have clarified it by myself:

Comment: I was initially worried that the solution x(t) = 0 for all t was different to the solution x(t) = 0 for t < b, but they are the same in the sense of uniqueness I think. Uniqueness guarantees that on a time interval centred on t = 0 any solution is the same, in this case the time interval is (-infinity, infinity), then the solution x(t) = 0 for t < b is still "a solution on this time interval", just a restricted domain?

Comment: If you're given an interval $I$ from the uniqueness theorem, and then choose $b$ so that your function has a jump discontinuity in this interval $I$, then of course it is not a solution on $I$. And it can't be, because the only function which satisfies the ODE for all $t\in I$ and also satisfies the initial condition $x(0)=0$ is the function given by the uniqueness theorem: $x(t)=0$ for all $t\in I$.

Comment: Sure, and if we say the interval I was $(-a, a)$, and the only solution here is x(t) = 0, and I define z:(-a/2, a/2) --> R by z(t) = 0, then this is still a solution right? As in, it's still the same solution on I, just a restricted domain?

Comment: It's not a solution on $I$, since it's not defined for all $t \in I$, but it's a solution on the smaller interval of course.

Comment: Yes, it's the same solution just on a smaller interval, and hence does not violate uniqueness

Answer (score 1):

$z(t)$ as defined above is a solution for finite time ($t<b$)

But then isn't that the same thing as $z(t) = 0$

Comment: I don't really understand what finite time means, does it mean that the value of $t$ is finite? Or that we are considering $t$ only in some interval $(a, b)$? Typing this out the latter seems likely not to be what it means...

Comment: If we have a solution that is clearly not true a $t=b$ then it might be true when $t>b$ or $t<b$ but we cannot ride over the discontinuity.  Since the we have the initial conditions when $t=0, z(t)$ is a solution right up until the solution "blows up."

Comment: The solution of $x'(t) = -x, x(0) > 0$ goes to zero, but not in finite time.:)

Comment: Right, but in the second example I gave, it is clearly not a solution at $t = \frac{1}{x_{0}}$, but is being regarded as a solution by my lecturer and we seem to be "riding over" this discontinuity as you say.

Comment: No "riding over".  Your function $x(t)$ does not have a left-sided limit at $t = 1/x_{0}$, hence cannot be extended to $t = 1/x_{0}$ and beyond.  BTW, Arnol'd explains the example $x' = x^2$ in the first chapter, and if your instructor's papers have not been cited as much as Arnol'd's, you should trust the scholar with a stronger publication record.:)

Comment: Haha ok I will be sure to check that book out

Answer (score 0):

In ODE theory, a solution is unique not for an ODE, but for an *initial value problem* (IVP) for an ODE.  The IVP is specified by giving: (1) the ODE, and (2) the initial condition.  Your $z(t)$ fails to satisfy the original initial condition, unless $x_{0}$.

Comment: Do you mean that the solution must solve all possible *initial value problems* - like the one that solved $\frac{dx}{dt} = x^{2}$ had an explicit dependency on $x_{0}$ and was a solution for all possible values of $x_{0}$. Whereas $z$ only solves $x(0) = x_{0} = 0$?

Comment: No, the solution must solve a specific IVP (i.e., a specific ODE + a specific initial condition).  In essence, one should think of an ODE geometrically, as a vector field on a surface (manifold), which specifies for each point $x$ the instantaneous velocity vector $v(x)$ at which a particle should pass that point.  When we fix a specific $x_{0}$ (initial condition), we ask, what function of time $\phi(t)$ will satisfy:
$
\phi(0) = x_{0}
$ and
$
\phi'(t) = v(x) \mbox{ whenever } x = \phi(t).
$
See V. Arnol'd's book "Ordinary Differential Equations."

Comment: I don't mean "solve all possible *initial value problems*", but that it must satisfy the initial condition for each possible initial condition? Like the solution does in the second case? I'm struggling to put this into words properly.

Comment: The $v(x)$ is the instantaneous velocity flow, and a solution $\phi(t)$ is the motion of a particle that, when passing through location $\phi(t) = x$, has velocity $v(x)$.

Comment: Yes to your last comment.  And, do read at least Chapters 1 and 2 of Arnol'd.

Comment: Ok, I think I am starting to get it, thank you for your help! So does the solution $x(t)$ have to be explicitly dependent on $x_{0}$ in the sense that if I choose any $x_{0}$ then the solution will satisfy that at $t = 0$ it takes the value $x_{0}$, that is, $x(0) = x_{0}$? So it can't work only for specific IVPs?

Comment: I definitely will read those chapters, thank you for the recommendation! Am I on the right lines with my previous comment?

Comment: Yes.   Your $x_{0}$ is the location where you first insert your weightless particle to be carried by the velocity field $v(x)$.  This location determines the particle's entire subsequent trajectory (which is your solution to the IVP).  Different locations of initial insertion lead to different trajectories.

Comment: Ok this makes a lot more sense, however my lecturer seemed to do a similar thing to what I did to show there were infinitely many solutions to the initial value problem $x(0) = 0$, and used a function similar to mine that did not take an arbitrary value of $x_{0}$ for $t = 0$ as you said was required, I have a screenshot of the section of the notes, but I am not sure how to send an image?

Comment: This was for a different ODE*

Comment: Here is a link to a screenshot of the lecture notes I am talking about https://www.dropbox.com/home/Stack%20Exchange%20Question, hopefully this works!

Comment: Doesn't, but I think I know what your question is now.  For the solution of an IVP to be unique, there are certain smoothness requirements on $v(x)$.  If these are broken, an IVP can have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Right, sorry this should work https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d1st1fa4mdyxth0/AACrIG9hppPP8SUBSRKSMMK3a?dl=0. It makes sense to me that the $z$ I defined isn't a valid solution as it can't satisfy all possible initial value problems at $t = 0$, i.e. it is not true that $z(0) = x_{0}$, it is only true that $z(0) = 0$. If this is a required condition for $z$ to be a valid solution I understand. What now is confusing me is that my lecturer doesn't seem to be doing the same thing ;)

Comment: See bottom of page 36 here: https://books.google.com/books?id=JUoyqlW7PZgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=arnold+ordinary+differential+equations&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKuteG7eLPAhWDWj4KHVPMBxsQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=Counterexample&f=false

Can't speak intelligently to what your instructor was trying to do; best to contact them directly.

Comment: Ok I'll have a read of that now, I am still slightly confused by what defines a valid solution however and as to why $z$ is not a solution

Comment: In the example on the bottom of page 36 that you linked, the solution $x(t) = 0$ is not able to take any possible value of the initial condition at time 0, so I am confused as it seemed like this was a necessary condition earlier?

Comment: " the solution x(t)=0 is not able to take any possible value of the initial condition at time 0"

Not understanding this.  Did you mean "to take any *other* possible value"?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is only able to take the value $x_{0}$ at time $t = 0$ when $x_{0} = 0$, but how I interpreted your earlier messages, likely falsely, is that for $x(t)$ to be a solution then for any value of $x_{0}$ we have that $x(0) = x_{0}$. Thank you again for all your help btw!

Comment: Upon reflection that seems very incorrect haha*

Comment: Try to switch temporarily from the active enquiry mode to reading mode.:)

Comment: Haha ok will do, I'm currently reading through the book you recommended